# How do you clear form field after submit/success?

Tags: php, ajax

I'm working with this exact same MailChimp PHP/AJAX subscribe processing form - [clear text value after success?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10403927/clear-text-value-after-success) - but I am absolutely stumped on how to actually get the form field to cleat after success.

Apparently to what Felix recommended here - [clear text value after success?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10403927/clear-text-value-after-success) -  the code works only if the span element exists at document load, and you have to call the if-statement after completion if using Ajax.

Could someone please help me? How do you clear the form field after it has been successfully completed by a user?

Here is the code:

```
    <?php  
    // store-address.php

    function storeAddress(){

        // Validation
        if(!$_GET['email']){ return "No email address provided"; } 

        if(!preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*$/i", $_GET['email'])) {
            return "Email address is invalid"; 
        }

        require_once('MCAPI.class.php');
        // grab an API Key from http://admin.mailchimp.com/account/api/
        $api = new MCAPI('my-api-key');

        // grab your List's Unique Id by going to http://admin.mailchimp.com/lists/
        // Click the "settings" link for the list - the Unique Id is at the bottom of that page. 
        $list_id = "my-list";

        if($api->listSubscribe($list_id, $_GET['email'], '') === true) {
            // It worked!   
            return 'Success! Check your email to confirm sign up.';
        }else{
            // An error ocurred, return error message   
            return 'Error: ' . $api->errorMessage;
        }

    }

    // If being called via ajax, autorun the function
    if($_GET['ajax']){ echo storeAddress(); }
    ?>
```

The form code:

```
    <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" id="signup" class="subscribe" method="get">

        <fieldset>
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="your email address" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send it" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <p id="response"><? require_once('inc/store-address.php'); if($_GET['submit']){ echo storeAddress(); } ?></p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/prototype.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/mailing-list.js"></script>
```

The mailing-list javascript code:

```
    // Load Events Listeners
    Event.observe(window, 'load', init, false);

    function init(){
        Event.observe('signup','submit',storeAddress);
    }

    // AJAX call sending sign up info to store-address.php
    function storeAddress(event) {
        // Update user interface
        $('response').innerHTML = 'Getting email address...';
        // Prepare query string and send AJAX request
        var pars = 'ajax=true&email=' + escape($F('email'));
        var myAjax = new Ajax.Updater('response', 'inc/store-address.php', {method: 'get', parameters: pars});
        Event.stop(event); // Stop form from submitting when JS is enabled
    }
```

Comment: Your e-mail validation regex doesn't allow certain characters, such as plus. Since anyone can submit a made-up "valid" email address, it's usually better to use a very simple format, such as `/.+@.+(?:\..+)*/` and send a confirmation email to make sure that they're telling the truth.

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions to this.

The less elegant one would be to create a JS function the resets every form field value manually.

The better way would be to store a hidden reset input in your form with an ID:

```
<input type="reset" id="blagh" style="display:none"/>
```

And simply 'click' it using jQuery:

```
$('#blagh').click();
```

Comment: Okay, thank you for your suggestions. But where exactly in my above code would I place the jQuery bit?

Comment: @user2485157 At the exact moment where you need to reset the form.

Answer (score 1):

The [jquery form plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/) has `resetForm()`. Just sayin'.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. But where exactly in my above code would I place that bit of code? In a separate script?